# Terraform resource as a module input variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When developing a terraform module, I sometimes find myself in the need to define different input variables for the same resources. For example, right now I need the NAME and ARN of the same AWS/ECS cluster for my module, so, I defined two variables in my module: `ecs_cluster_arn` and `ecs_cluster_name`.

For the sake of DRY, it would be very nice if I could just define the input variable `ecs_cluster` of type `aws_ecs_cluster` and the just use whatever I need inside my module.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: Anything stopping your module using the [`aws_ecs_cluster` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ecs_cluster) and looking up the ARN given the name?

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. To be honest, I didn't think about it, I guess that could work. It feels a little bit dirty to me though, why make a second request to fetch information that I already have?

Comment: I personally use data sources like this liberally in internal modules. For public modules the general recommendation is to allow people to pass things in as IDs and make them responsible for either passing it in from a data source, a resource, or a hardcoded ID for flexibility. For internal use though I just care about making the interface as simple as possible for users of the module and for that I can just ask for the name of the resource and use a data source to fetch more information in the module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an input variable whose [type constraint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html) is compatible with the schema of the `aws_ecs_cluster` resource type. Typically you'd write a subset type constraint that contains only the attributes the module actually needs. For example:

```
variable "ecs_cluster" {
  type = object({
    name = string
    arn  = string
  })
}
```

Elsewhere in the module, you can use `var.ecs_cluster.name` and `var.ecs_cluster.arn` to refer to those attributes. The caller of the module can pass in anything that's compatible with that type constraint, which includes a whole instance of the `aws_ecs_cluster` resource type, but would also include a literal object containing just those two attributes:

```
module "example" {
  # ...

  ecs_cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.example
}
```

```
module "example" {
  # ...

  ecs_cluster = {
    name = "blah"
    arn  = "arn:aws:yada-yada:blah"
  }
}
```

In many cases this would also allow passing the result of [the corresponding data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ecs_cluster) instead of the managed resource type. Unfortunately for this pairing in particular the data source for some reason uses the different attribute name `cluster_name` and therefore isn't compatible. That's unfortunate, and not the typical design convention for pairs of managed resource type and data source with the same name; I assume it was a design oversight.

```
module "example" {
  # ...

  # This doesn't actually work for the aws_ecs_cluster
  # data source because of a design quirk, but this would
  # be possible for most other pairings such as
  # the aws_subnet managed resource type and data source.
  ecs_cluster = data.aws_ecs_cluster.example
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you.